Does statfs always follow symbolic links?
It looks like the Linux statfs(2) system call (called through the POSIX statvfs() function) is dereferencing (following) the symbolic link and, therefore, showing the stats of the filesystem that the target file is located and not the filesystem that the symbolic link resides.
Is this expected and always guaranteed?
I checked the man page and I do not see the answer.

From the manpage: ELOOP  (statvfs()) Too many symbolic links were encountered in translating path.. I'd say it is somehow assumed. Have you checked the implementation or its history for further infos?

You can o_path |  o_nofollow open() a symbolic link, and then fstatfs it (i think).

@UlrichEckhardt The path might have symbolic links in the middle of the path, which always have to be followed. That can cause ELOOP. This is no indication wether the function will follow a symlink in the last component of the path. lstat for example gives an error of ELOOP too.

Original answer

The man page for [`statvfs()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statvfs.2.html) shows an error that can only occur if the function follows the symlinks:

ELOOP (statvfs()) Too many symbolic links were encountered in translating path.

By inference, the function follows the symlinks to the file at the end.
As pointed out by Goswin von Brederlow in a comment, that is incorrect.

Revised answer
As I noted in a comment response (to chicken-rice's comment):

It’s easier to document those [system calls] that don’t follow symlinks. There’s lstat() and … um, readlink(), and … that's about it. I may have missed some, but not many. Basically, system calls that take path name arguments follow symlinks unless explicitly documented not to.

You should look at path_resolution(7) and the POSIX entry Pathname Resolution and maybe the definition of Symbolic Link.
The key to the usefulness of symlinks is that almost all the system calls that take a filename follow symlinks automatcially so that symlinks act seamlessly.

The lstat() function doesn't follow symlinks when the last component of the name it is given is a symlink, but if the path has symlinks in it, those are followed (and can give rise to the ELOOP error).  And if the last component of the name doesn't point to a symlink, it behaves just like stat() does.  You can tell the difference from the information in the st_mode member of the struct stat data.

The readlink() function explicitly requires the path name to identify a symlink, and fails if the last component is not a symlink.  (Note, incidentally, that readlink() — for obscure backwards compatibility reasons — does not null-terminate the byte array, but it does tell you how long it is.)

The lchown() function — which, like chown(), allows you to change both owner and group — behaves like chown() when given a name that does not identify a symlink.

POSIX doesn't define lchmod(2) but it is available on some systems.  For most systems, the permissions on a symlink are immaterial, but macOS does heed them (you need read access on a symlink to be able to follow it).  Some other systems allow you to set the permissions on a symlink but the permissions do not affect the operation of the links.

The realpath() function reports a path name with no . or .. entries and no symlinks in it (if one can be deduced).


POSIX also defines a series of *at() functions.

faccessat()
fchmodat()
fchownat()
fstatat()
linkat()
mkdirat()
mkfifoat()
mknodat()
openat()
readlinkat()
renameat()
symlinkat()
unlinkat()
utimensat()

Some of these take a flag AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW to avoid following symlinks.  The open() and openat() functions take a flag option O_NOFOLLOW to tell it not to follow a symlink.  Obviously, when directed not to follow a symlink, they do not follow a symlink named as the last component of the path, but by default, they do follow such symlinks.
On macOS (Sonoma 14.5 used for testing, but the rules have applied for a long time, to many previous versions), the following sequence of commands illustrates some differences between stat() and lstat(), using a simple home-built command called fstat (to distinguish it from the more verbose system command stat).  It uses the stat() function unless passed the -l argument; then it uses lstat().
$ ls -l chk.build in-absentia bust-symlink
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff    12 Jun 10 07:49 bust-symlink -> non-existent
-r-xr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  1698 May 31 14:08 chk.build
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff     9 Jun 10 07:49 in-absentia -> chk.build
$ fstat chk.build
   Mode      Inode Links   UID   GID     Size    Modtime        Dev       RDev File
0100555   29288749     1   501    20     1698 1717186100   16777233          0 chk.build
$ fstat -l chk.build
   Mode      Inode Links   UID   GID     Size    Modtime        Dev       RDev File
0100555   29288749     1   501    20     1698 1717186100   16777233          0 chk.build
$ fstat in-absentia
   Mode      Inode Links   UID   GID     Size    Modtime        Dev       RDev File
0100555   29288749     1   501    20     1698 1717186100   16777233          0 in-absentia
$ fstat -l in-absentia
   Mode      Inode Links   UID   GID     Size    Modtime        Dev       RDev File
0120755   29826094     1   501    20        9 1718027340   16777233          0 in-absentia
$ fstat -l bust-symlink
   Mode      Inode Links   UID   GID     Size    Modtime        Dev       RDev File
0120755   29826106     1   501    20       12 1718027392   16777233          0 bust-symlink
$ fstat bust-symlink
   Mode      Inode Links   UID   GID     Size    Modtime        Dev       RDev File
fstat: failed to stat file bust-symlink: error (2) No such file or directory
$

You can see that the mode, printed in octal, uses 0100000 for regular files and 0120000 for symlinks (and other values for other file types).

Thanks, I noticed that error although I was expecting it to be documented more explicitly. I also tried to find complete list of the system calls that dereference the symbolic links and I could not find it.

It’s easier to document those that don’t follow symlinks.  There’s lstat() and … um, readlink(), and … that's about it.  I may have missed some, but not many.  Basically, system calls that take path name arguments follow symlinks unless explicitly documented not to.

Note: lstat() gives an error of ELOOP too so the reasoning in the answer is flawed.

@GoswinvonBrederlow — yes, you were right.  I've rewritten the answer pretty much completely.

Thanks for very comprehensive answer.

O_NOFOLLOW exists to solve the TOCTOU security problem of giving a filename to a setuid program that opens the file for output. If the program checks that the original user has access to the file, then you replace the file with a symlink to a system file, it will overwrite the system file.
